# How to get text from JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I'm trying to understand the Scanner function, but I can't seem to understand it.

I'm making a program to calculate the BMI (body mass index) and it's practically done, except that I can't make the calculation! Everything works fine except for when I click the "ok" button.

Had to take away my code so my collegues won't copy my code, like they've made in the past, will be posting again after friday.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Scanner for this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html should help. getText() retrieves text from JTextField.

Comment: 'Cause if i don't, the numbers i wrote in the JTextField won't work, at least, it didn't worked, and i thinks it's because it's not receiving the numbers from the keyboard...

Comment: Huh? There are proper methods to get input from JTextFields, like the examples from the link I posted above. And the Scanner class is not one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first thing there is no poblem with Scanner things and its not required when we use GUI.

its useful only for console input/output.

so when you get text it will be in string format so parse it to double like

```
String val = txt1.getText();
double valueDouble = Double.parseDouble(val);
```

and handle the parse exception using try/catch

so replace the piece of code below

```
 Scanner dado1 = new Scanner(txt1.getText());
            System.out.println(dado1);
                if(dado1.hasNextDouble()){
                    tamanho = dado1.nextDouble();
                }
            Scanner dado2 = new Scanner(txt2.getText());
                if(dado2.hasNextDouble()){
                    peso = dado2.nextDouble();
                }
```

to

```
String t1 = txt1.getText();
if(!"".equals(t1))
tamanho = Double.parseDouble(t1);


String t2 = txt2.getText();
if(!"".equals(t2))
peso = Double.parseDouble(t2);
```

i tried to run your program but i got the exception saying -> container does not have parent attribute.

so what i did is i have added a parent container inside your ok button action listener

and it works well.

container to be added is

```
final JDesktopPane desk = new JDesktopPane();
                    setContentPane(desk);
```

to your

```
JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(desk,"Seu IMC é:"+ (result/ peso));
```

but you have passed null as the first argement.

so it should become like below

```
   ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            String t1 = txt1.getText();
            if(!"".equals(t1))
            tamanho = Double.parseDouble(t1);


            String t2 = txt2.getText();
            if(!"".equals(t2))
            peso = Double.parseDouble(t2);
              result = tamanho*tamanho;
            if (ok != null){
                System.out.println(result);
                System.out.println(peso);
                final JDesktopPane desk = new JDesktopPane();
                setContentPane(desk);
                JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(desk,"Seu IMC é:"+ (result/ peso));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well it actually helped a lot in here ! It at least gets to the end of the execution, but it still not showing the result from the numbers i've typed in here... does it showed there ?

Comment: yes dont use scanner use like i have shown at the begining of my post i have updated it to read from text field and parse it..

Comment: i have updated the right way of reading value from text field..check it and let me know '

Comment: oops my mistake haha, i forgot to delete the import Scanner, well it's running now but the result is always NaN, thought that's not even a number... Any idea why ?

Comment: yea i got it..you are doing calculation and reading text value before entering the values in text so its coming as 0.0/0.0...so move the reading and calculation code inside the ok listener action performed method...see updated same answer

Comment: Well, what can i say ? You rock, dude ! Thanks for the help man, hope i can help you some day too ! Damn, you really helped a lot ! Thanks a lot bro !

Comment: ha thats ok..just vote up and accept my answer if it has helped you..thanks for nice question

Comment: Shure, it's done ! Sorry, i'm new here so i'm asking, answer me if/when you can... Putting that inside the ok action, it's converting the String to Double ? It's just that i'm beggining and sometimes i do things that i don't know, like now haha

Comment: yes inside ok , it is converting string into double using parseDouble method of Double wrapper class and that is how we need it before we do calculation...nothing to worry..we should do mistakes to learn the things..otherwise we wont learn...ask anytime...will surely help my best

Answer (score 0):

you may simply [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) instead of Scanner:

```
tamanho = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());
```

Comment: share your updated code

Comment: showed and working now haha thx ! you helped a lot also, thx a lot for your support !